# Fast way to find what histogram bin a single value will fall into?

Tags: python

I have an example histogram whose bins look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If I'm given a value like `5.6`, I want to be able to get the index of the bin list where the given value would fall into in the histogram, so in this example it would be `i = 4` which is `5`. I can also assume that the given value will always be within the range of the bins. I know I could do this with a loop and do some comparison checks, but is there a faster way?

Comment: If 5.6 goes in the bin at index 4 where does 0.6 go?

Comment: The list represents bins so 5.6 going into index 4 means that it's between 5 and 6.

Comment: But that's not what I asked. What bin does 0.6 go into? I think your logic is off by one. By your logic 1 - 2 goes in bin index 0, and that leaves no bin for values less than one.

Comment: I can assume that the only given values will be in the range of the bins, so 0.6 would not be a value asked for. The given list is just an example and is just to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I know to do this in Python is with the [bisect library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). It will give you values one greater than what you are looking for, so you'll need to subtract one.

```
import bisect

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
bisect.bisect(l, 5.6) - 1
# 4
```

For larger lists, it is orders of magnitude faster than python loops:

```
import bisect

l = list(range(100000))
n = 79587.6

%timeit next(x[0]-1 for x in enumerate(l) if x[1] > n)
# 8.33 ms ± 22.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit bisect.bisect(l, n) - 1
# 800 ns ± 0.769 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

While Mark suggested using bisect, I'd also like to mention using next with no imports.

```
value = 5.6
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

next(x[0] - 1 for x in enumerate(lis) if x[1] > value)

# 4
```